# split string into string in haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, split

How can I split a `string` into another `string` without using `Data.List.Split` function?
To be more concrete: to turn `"Abc"` into `"['A','b','c']"`

Answer (score 5):

If you want literally the string `"['A','b','c']"` as opposed to the expression `['A','b','c']` which is identical to `"Abc"` since in Haskell the `String` type is a synonym for `[Char]`, then something like the following will work:

```
'[': (intercalate "," $ map show "Abc") ++ "]"
```

The function `intercalate` is in `Data.List` with the type

```
intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
```

It intersperses its first argument between the elements of the list given as its second argument.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you meant how to turn `"Abc"`into `["A", "b", "c"]`. This is quite simple, if the string to split is `s`, then this will do the trick:

```
map (\x -> [x]) s
```

Comment: or perhaps the OP meant turn `"Abc"` into `['A','b','c']` which can be done with `\x->x` or if you want to go point free: `id`.  :-)

Comment: actually i need exactly what is written in example

Comment: What Philip JF means: In Haskell `String` is simply a list of `Char`s. Thus, "Abc" is *exactly* the same as `['A', 'b', 'c']`.

Answer (score 3):

Fire up ghci to see that the expressions you wrote are the same:

```
Prelude> ['A','b','c']
"Abc"
```